# Sonar-cxx don't find bugs and others

Tags: sonarqube

because I will check my C/C++ projects using sonar for bugs, vulnerabilities and others I've installed sonar v5.6.3 and sonar-cxx v0.9.6.
To evaluate sonar for my purposes I have took the c example of the sonar examples and extended the file main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* NOK, according to the MISRA C 2004 20.9 rule, stdio.h must not be used in embedded system's production code */
#include <mylib.h>

int main(void) {
  int   a;
  char  buffer[10];
  char  index           = 1;
  int   x               = ADD(40, 2);
  int   y               = fun(40, 2);

  buffer[10]    = 1;    /* Vulnerability:   Aray index out of bound                     */
  buffer[a]     = 'a';  /* Vulnerability:   Array index ist used before limits check    */
  buffer[index] = '1';  /* Code smell:      'char' type used as array index             */
  if (1 == a)           /* Bug:             Access to an uninitialized value            */
  {
      printf("a = 1");
  }

  a = 0;
  if (x != 42)
  { /* NOK, empty code blocks generate violations */
  }

  x /= a;           /* Bug:             Division by zero */

  printf("40 + 2 = %d\n", x);
  printf("fun = %d\n", y);
}

int fun(int a, int b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

Further I have changed the file sonar-project.properties to parse the code using sonar-cxx

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=org.sonarqube:c-simple-sq-scanner
sonar.projectName=C :: Simple Project :: SonarQube Scanner
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src
sonar.cxx.includeDirectories=lib

# Language, needed for SonarQube < 4.2
sonar.language=c++

# The build-wrapper output dir
# sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=/path/to/build-wrapper/output/dir

# Optional comma-separated list of additional libraries folders (such as /usr/include)
# sonar.cfamily.library.directories=lib

# Optional specific predefined macros
# sonar.cfamily.predefinedMacros=#define MY_MACRO(a) ((a)+1),#define DEBUG

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

While running sonar-runner (v2.5) I don't see error messages:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: D:\RnD_Tools\sonar-scanner-2.5\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: C:\Users\ralfebert\Downloads\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\c\c-sonar-runner\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.5
INFO: Java 1.8.0_73 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\ralfebert\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=129ms
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\ralfebert\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=5ms
INFO: Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=193ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=118ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=1528ms
INFO: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: -------------  Scan C :: Simple Project :: SonarQube Scanner
INFO: Language is forced to c++
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=250ms
INFO: Base dir: C:\Users\ralfebert\Downloads\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\c\c-sonar-runner
INFO: Working dir: C:\Users\ralfebert\Downloads\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\c\c-sonar-runner\.sonar
INFO: Source paths: src
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
INFO: Index files
INFO: 1 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for c++: Sonar way
INFO: JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : C:\Users\ralfebert\Downloads\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\c\c-sonar-runner\target\jacoco.exec
INFO: JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: C:\Users\ralfebert\Downloads\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\c\c-sonar-runner\target\jacoco-it.exec
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=10ms
INFO: Sensor CxxSquidSensor
INFO: Scanner found '0' report files
INFO: Cannot find a report for 'sonar.cxx.compiler.reportPath'
INFO: Project 'org.sonarqube:c-simple-sq-scanner' Cycles:0 Feedback cycles:0 Tangles:0 Weight:0.0
INFO: Sensor CxxSquidSensor (done) | time=178ms
INFO: Sensor CxxCoverageSensor
INFO: Sensor CxxCoverageSensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=6ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=22ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for c++
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=9ms
INFO: Calculating CPD for 1 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 50ms, dir size=31 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 7ms, zip size=11 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 141ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/org.sonarqube:c-simple-sq-scanner
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVgF6GhDsPC8lDzvfGdL
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 7.584s
INFO: Final Memory: 49M/250M
INFO:  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After looking for the result in my browser I see:

- Bugs: 0
- Vulnerabilities: 0
- Code Smells: 0
- Debt: 0
- Duplications: 0%
- Duplicated Blocks: 0
- Lines of Code: 24

which was unexpected. To check my installation I have made a similar test with the java example and for this project I see bugs and vulnerabilities.

Is sonar-cxx a special case and I must activate the checks manually? Can someone help me to solve my problem?

Thanks in advice, Ralf Ebert

Comment: So is the code above C or C++? They are different languages. And `char` as index into an array is fine, it is an integer type. Different language have different semantics. You cannot deduce from something being wrong or correct in e.g. Java to be the same in C or C++.

Comment: The code is C but it should be parsed with the C++ parser. Before I have started the evaluation I've took a look to the rules of **sonar-cxx** and found the rule  **'char' type used as array index** for code smells. Definitely the division by zero in  **x /= a;** is a bug and I expected that it should be found by the parser ...

Comment: This is a very bad approach! As I mentioned, they are different languages. Identical syntax can have different semantics (e.g. `const` qualifier, `auto`, ...). **Never ever** treat C code as C++! (I did not say there are not errors in your code, but indexing via `char` is not worse than indexing via any other integer. Actually it is converted to `int` anyway before being used and signed indexes peer se "smell"). Btw. A modern compiler like gcc will find most faults already. The difision by zero might be problematic, though.

Comment: Ok, you are right - the approach was bad. Meanwhile I have made the test with the c++ example but the result is the same --- I see the number of lines, but all other values are zero :-/

Answer (score 1):

From the [Running the Analysis](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Running-the-analysis) page of the Sonar-cxx wiki on GitHub:

> *The C++ Community plugin won't execute neither test runners nor coverage tracers nor static checkers itself. All this data has to be provided in form of reports.*

Also on this page is a link to the [Running Tools](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Running-tools) page. This links to several other pages that explain how to generate the reports used by Sonar-cxx. For example, you can use [Cppcheck](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Code-checkers#cppcheck) to run a static analysis of the code. Save the output to a directory somewhere within your project, and set the **sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath** property (see [here](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Supported-configuration-properties#sonarcxxcppcheckreportpath)) to point to that directory.

Comment: Indeed, the code in this question does not look testable at all. Where are test, coverage and resulting analysis bound to specific lines of code? (e.g. with LCOV or any other coverage format)

Answer (score 0):

See this important note about sonar-cxx plugin:

https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Running-tools

---

I'm using build-wrapper configuration on Sonarcloud.io for the C language family Sonar plugin.

Then you need to run wrapper before the sonar-scanner to `make` your sources and output some meaningful results from your compiler (you can also use e.g. cppcheck as mentioned above).

Scanner will consume output after having the `sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output` path set.

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw-output \
  ... your other options
```

See https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/cfamily/ for details.

Comment: do you have any documentation to explain how to use this?